# How do I partially differentiate the multivariable equation $z^2=x^2+y^2$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

How do I partially differentiate the multivariable equation $z^2=x^2+y^2$?

I am supposed to find $f_x$ and $f_y$. Thanks!

I had several attempts at figuring out implicit differentiation, but I am confused.

Comment: Take a look at this link: http://www.math.harvard.edu/archive/21a_spring_09/PDF/11-02-03-partial-derivatives.pdf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} z^2 &= \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x^2 + y^2) \\
2 z \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} &= 2x + 2 y \frac{\partial y}{\partial x} \\
\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} &= \frac{x}{z} \\
\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} &= \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}
\end{align*}$$

Since
$\partial y/\partial x = 0$